# How to slide manually to the next slide in ion-slide

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using ion-slide in ionic4 and i want to go for next slide manually by clicking on button. I have seen the ion-slide documentation in which they have mention **slideNext** method. But I don't know how to use this method for changing slide.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ya, I got the solution. In ionic 4 you have to import IonSlides instead of Slides.

**home.ts**

```
import { IonSlides} from '@ionic/angular';


 export class HomePage {

      @ViewChild('mySlider')  slides: IonSlides;

      swipeNext(){
        this.slides.slideNext();
      }

    }
```

**home.html**

```
 <ion-slides pager="true"  pager="false" #mySlider>

   <ion-slide>
   </ion-slide>

   <ion-slide>
   </ion-slide>

    <ion-button (click)="swipeNext()">Next</ion-button>

 </ion-slides>
```

Comment: Hi @Tahseen , Can you elaborate  **horizontal scroll inside ion-slide**  [Ref. Url](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-horizontal-scroll-inside-ion-slide/96848)

Comment: Any way to slide to last side on click?

Answer (score 5):

In Angular 8 :

```
@ViewChild('mySlider', { static: true }) slides: IonSlides;
```

Answer (score 5):

Is simple and just necessary in html

```
<ion-slides #slides pager="true">
   <ion-slide>1
   </ion-slide>

   <ion-slide>2
   </ion-slide>
 </ion-slides>

  <ion-button (click)="slides.slidePrev()" > Prev </ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="slides.slideNext()" > Next </ion-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way (same as above answer but I tried to make it simpler):

```js
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

class abc {
  @ViewChild(Slides)slides: Slides;

  public next(){
    this.slides.slideNext();
  }

  public prev(){
    this.slides.slidePrev();
  }
}
```